# A question about the time complexity of max-heapify

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, heap

everyone. I am new here.

I am learning algorithms by myself using the "Introduction to Algorithms" wirtten by Thomas H. Cormen etc. And I got a question at which I am so confused, so I came here to seek some help. If anyone could help me, I would be very thankful.

The question is about the complexity of max-heapify. It is an exercise of Chapter 6 of that book, it says

> Show that the worst-case running time of MAX-HEAPIFY on a heap of size
> n is (lgn). lg is the logarithm to the base 2.

Could anyone explain to me that why the complexity is (lgn)? Why isn't there an upper bound like O(lgn)?

The book say that the running time of MAX-HEAPIFY is O(lgn), I understand that because the height of the tree is O(lgn), but why does this change to (lgn) just because of the worst-case?

Comment: Hi there. I'm not sure myself, but is https://stats.stackexchange.com/ a better place for this question as it doesn't seem to be programming-specific?

Comment: Thank you! This is my first question in such kinds of community and I didn't know where the best place is. I'll ask my question there.

Comment: When you're asked to show a lower bound, it doesn't mean that there isn't also an upper bound.

Comment: @Michelle I think this is an ok place for the question, since a heap is a common programming-language data structure. I think it has a lot more in common with programming than it does with statistics.

Comment: @PaulHankin Yeah, it is related to data structure, but I think my question here is really a mathematical problem. I guess I am still not fully understand how this asympotic analysis of algorithms works.